# Wanting to migrate a wordpress project from localhost to a local domain name server/virtual host

Tags: virtual-machine, apache-http-server, localhost, node.js, npm

I have a WordPress project that currently resides in WAMP on the standard localhost server. I also have node.js installed to automate my workflow.

I would like to create a local domain server/virtual host to host my WordPress project locally for now while I am in development env, so instead of entering localhost/workshop/, I would want to enter workshop.local.

If I add a new virtual host via the localhost page wizard, would that automatically set it up for me or do I also have to do some additional tasks to make it work?

I am hesitant to do so, since I am not familiar with the process.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I was going to delete this question, but if anyone else has the same question, My answer would be to follow the wordpress.org on 'Changing The Site URL'. Here is the link to do just that:

https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/

I will try it out soon and will comment if I was successful in doing so.